# Android studio : Paste option is not working

Tags: android-studio, paste

today my android studio is not working for paste commands and mouse paste option. However copying in clipboard works.

[image]

Invalidated cache and restarted and did all EDIT commands reset from settings.

[image]

If pressed command for history paste (combination ctrl+shift+v) it shows copied objects but cant paste anything on editor.

Please recommend actions if I am missing anything.
Please note after testing I found only (combination ctrl+shift+alt+v) works.